# JavaScript does not run if imported after jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

When I import my script like this after jQuery, my script doesn't run (no console output).

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

<script type= "text/javascript" src = "main.js"/>
```

However, if I reverse the order of my imports, my script runs just fine. 
Not really sure why.

Here is `main.js`

```
// Manipulates palette colors represented by divs
function main(){

    // Randomize the colors in the divs on page load / refresh
    randomizeColors();

    // Add click listeners on change pal buttons
    addClickListenerChangePalButton();

    // Add listener on randomize button
    console.log("adding listener on radn button")
    addRandomizeButtonListener();
}

// Button 1 changes div 1 visibility to on, all others to off etc.
function addClickListenerChangePalButton(){

    console.log("addClickListenerChangePalButton");

    var divs = [];

    divs[0] = document.getElementById("div0");
    divs[1] = document.getElementById("div1");
    divs[2] = document.getElementById("div2");
    divs[3] = document.getElementById("div3");
    divs[4] = document.getElementById("div4");
    divs[5] = document.getElementById("div5");    
    divs[6] = document.getElementById("div6");
    divs[7] = document.getElementById("div7");

    console.log("divs.length is "+divs.length);

    var palButton = document.getElementById("palButton");

    palButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var innerHtml = this.innerHTML;
        if(innerHtml === "1"){
            this.innerHTML = "2";
            makeVisible(divs.slice(0,2));
            makeInvisible(divs.slice(2,divs.length));
        } 
        else if (innerHtml === "2"){
            this.innerHTML = "4";
            makeVisible(divs.slice(0,4));
            makeInvisible(divs.slice(4,divs.length));
        }
        else if (innerHtml === "4"){
            this.innerHTML = "8";
            makeVisible(divs.slice(0,divs.length));
        }
        else if (innerHtml === "8"){
            this.innerHTML = "1";
            makeVisible(divs.slice(0,1));
            makeInvisible(divs.slice(1,divs.length));
        }
    })

    function makeVisible(divs){
        console.log("makeVisible");
        console.log("divs.length is "+divs.length);
        divs.forEach(function(div) {
            console.log("iteration...");
            //$(div).fadeOut(200);
            div.style.visibility='visible'
        }, this);
    }

    function makeInvisible(divs){
        console.log("makeInvisible");
        console.log("divs.length is "+divs.length);
        divs.forEach(function(div) {
            console.log("iteration...");
            div.style.visibility='hidden'
        }, this);
    }
}

// Add click listener on randomize colors button
function addRandomizeButtonListener(){
    var randBtn = document.getElementById("randButton");
    console.log("adding event listener");
    console.log("randBtn");
    randBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
        randomizeColors();
        console.log("colors changed");
    });
}

// randomizes colors
function randomizeColors(){

    console.log("querying!");

    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

    console.log("defining function!");

    var callBack = function(div){
        var randInt = getRandomInt(0,Math.pow(255, 3));
        var hexString = randInt.toString(16);
        // backgroundColor is more browser compatible than background which does not work in Fire Fox
        item.style.backgroundColor = "#"+hexString;
        //console.log(item);
    }

    console.log("looping!");

    // Looping through node array should use for-loop for browser compatability reasons
    for(i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
        item = divs[i];
        callBack(item);
        //console.log(item);
    }

    // inputs.forEach(function(item){
    //     var randInt = getRandomInt(0,Math.pow(255, 3));
    //     var hexString = randInt.toString(16);
    //     item.setAttribute("value","#"+hexString);
    //     console.log(item);
    // });
}

// Returns random int [min,max)
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

main();
```

Comment: Define *"my script doesn't run."*. Do you get an error in your developer's console?

Comment: This is a big gotcha... script tags have to be closed. so `<script type= "text/javascript" src = "main.js"/>` will not work, but `<script type= "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>` should. Give it a try.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._ - the reason it works before the jQuery is that it reads the jQuery end script tag

Comment: @arbuthnott You're right, it worked. Never would have guessed considering the script runs when the imports are in reverse order.